# Does objects initialized to a property of AppController in beforeFilter get destroyed before beforeRender is called?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to integrate Facebook into one of my cakePHP2 apps and I initialize the facebook class in `beforeFilter` like so:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'myappid98a232466',
        'secret' => 'myappsecret8e06342c5',
    ));

}
```

Later in `beforeRender` when I try to access methods of Facebook i get a fetal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object

```
public function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('fbLoginUrl', $this->Facebook->getLoginUrl());
}
```

The value of `$this->Facebook` on `beforeRender()` is set to `null`. Why is the object getting destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The beforeFilter is not being run

Most likely there is a beforeFilter defined in a child class that is not calling the parent. As such, the beforeFilter in the AppController is not run, and the property is never set. fix by:

```
class FoosController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        ...
        parent::beforeFilter(); // added
    }

}
```